# what is drupal 6's version of hook_user_cancel for drupal7?

Tags: 6, users

I'm trying to execute some custom code in drupal 6 after i ban/block a user.  What would be the appropriate way to do this?  I tried using hook_user specifically looking for an 'update' $op when I block a user, but no 'update' operation seems to get passed into my hook, only 'load' gets passed.  I guess the equivalent of this in Drupal 7 would be hook_user_cancel.

Answer (score 3):

[hook_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6) has an operation for **delete**, it does however lack an option for **ban** or **block**. In this case you should use the [**rules**](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and implement a custom action that gets called when a user is banned, the action being in your custom code. There's a few Drupalcon presentations on [Rules, Conditions and Actions](http://drupal.org/node/298476) available on Drupal.org.